# Why is the “root.after ()” method not stoppable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, button, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple tool-path program with directional buttons. It works, but sometimes releasing the button is ineffective and the turtle stops just clicking the "Home" button. Else it just runs continuously as if I did not release the button.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

def showPos():
    monitor.delete('1.0', END)
    monitor.insert(END, "X: " + str(tool.ycor()) +" Z: " + str(tool.xcor()))

def goHome():
    tool.home()
    showPos()
    stop_move()

def goUp():
    tool.sety(tool.ycor() + 10)

def goDown():
    tool.sety(tool.ycor() - 10)

def goRight():
    tool.setx(tool.xcor() + 10)

def goLeft():
    tool.setx(tool.xcor() - 10)

def stop_move():
    global jobid
    root.after_cancel(jobid)

def move(direction):
    global jobid

    if direction == "-X":
        goDown()

    if direction == "+X":
        goUp()    

    if direction == "-Z":
        goLeft()

    if direction == "+Z":
        goRight()    

    jobid = root.after(10, move, direction)
    showPos()

jobid = None

root = Tk()
root.title("CNC Lathe")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.register_shape("wnmg.gif")

tool = RawTurtle(screen, shape="wnmg.gif")
tool.pencolor("white")

monitor = Text(root, height=1, width=16, font="Helvetica")
monitor.pack()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
middleFrame = Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

for direction in ("-X", "+X", "-Z", "+Z"):
    if direction == "+X":
        button = Button(topFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack()

    if direction == "-X":
        button = Button(bottomFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack()

    if direction == "-Z":
        button = Button(middleFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack(side=LEFT)

    if direction == "+Z":
        button = Button(middleFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack(side=RIGHT)   

    button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda event, direction=direction: move(direction))
    button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event: stop_move())

Button(middleFrame, text="Home", command=goHome).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to set the variable "jobid" to "None" after the "root.after_cancel ()" method, but nothing changed. At times this does not seem to detect the release of the button. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: ***"does not seem to detect the release of the button"***: It does, but you need a condition to stop further calling `root.after(10, move, direction)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make your code work with your `jobid` model, and although I could improve it, the flaw eventually surfaced -- I can't say exactly why.  You have to consider that, in your implementation, `jobid` doesn't always represent a pending job, it could be one that has fired successfuly.

Another issue to consider is the timing of:

```
jobid = root.after(10, move, direction)
```

The 10ms time has to be greater than the time it takes to execute the `move()` method, plus time to react.  That is, if you can't draw the minimal size box (10 x 10) without repitition getting in your way, you again need to incress this time.

Below is my rework of your code using a simple state variable instead of the job id (plus some other changes.)  It seems to solve the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

def showPos():
    monitor.delete('1.0', END)
    monitor.insert(END, "X: " + str(tool.ycor()) + " Z: " + str(tool.xcor()))

def goHome():
    tool.home()
    showPos()

def goUp():
    tool.sety(tool.ycor() + 10)

def goDown():
    tool.sety(tool.ycor() - 10)

def goRight():
    tool.setx(tool.xcor() + 10)

def goLeft():
    tool.setx(tool.xcor() - 10)

pressing = False

def start_move(event):
    global pressing

    event.widget.unbind('<ButtonPress-1>')  # unbind event handler inside handler(s)

    pressing = True

    move(event)

def stop_move(event):
    global pressing

    pressing = False

    event.widget.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', start_move)

def move(event):
    if not pressing:
        return

    direction = event.widget['text']

    if direction == '-X':
        goDown()
    elif direction == '+X':
        goUp()    
    elif direction == '-Z':
        goLeft()
    elif direction == '+Z':
        goRight()    

    showPos()

    root.after(75, move, event)

root = Tk()
root.title("CNC Lathe")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')
# screen.register_shape("wnmg.gif")

# tool = RawTurtle(screen, shape="wnmg.gif")
tool = RawTurtle(screen, shape='turtle')
tool.pencolor('white')

monitor = Text(root, height=1, width=16, font='Helvetica')
monitor.pack()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
middleFrame = Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

for direction in ('-X', '+X', '-Z', '+Z'):
    if direction == '+X':
        button = Button(topFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack()

    if direction == '-X':
        button = Button(bottomFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack()

    if direction == '-Z':
        button = Button(middleFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack(side=LEFT)

    if direction == '+Z':
        button = Button(middleFrame, text=direction)
        button.pack(side=RIGHT)   

    button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', start_move)
    button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_move)

Button(middleFrame, text="Home", command=goHome).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I changed the cursor to a turtle as I didn't have your `"wnmg.gif"` image to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I tried the modifications and I found that it solves the problem, even if I stay at the 10 ms interval (but I reduced the increment to 1). Thank you again very much!